# expected value of map generate algorithm

Tags: probability-theory

I designed a program to create a map in my 2D game program. And I have three questions...

**algorithm:**

**step1:**

```
create a cell in (0,0), and select it as first cell, and mark the step1 is round 0
```

**step2:**

```
in round i (start from 1), for every cell created in i - 1 round : 
    for adjacent index in up, down, left, and right:
        generate a random value between (0, 1), create a new cell in this index if the random value if less than P
```

**step3:**

```
if some cells created in this round, go to step 2, else finish this algorithm
```

**here is my python code**

```python
    def calc(P):
        mp = {}
        s = (0, 0)
        ds = [(-1,0), (0,-1), (1,0),(0,1)]
        q = [s]
        ql = 0
        mp[s] = 1
        while len(q) > ql:
            idx = q[ql]
            round = mp.get(idx, -1)
            ql += 1
            for d in ds:
                cur_idx = (idx[0] + d[0], idx[1] + d[1])
                if mp.get(cur_idx, -1) == -1 and P(round) > random.random():
                    mp[cur_idx] = round + 1
                    q.append(cur_idx)
        return len(mp) # count of cells
```

this algorithm will create a map by a function that gradually decays based on the generation rounds. But I don't know how to calculate the expected value of how many cells will be created by this algorithm. the $P$ is a function about round

**question 1:**  what's the expected value of how many cells will be created when $P(\mathtt{round}) = C$, where $C$ is a constant value and greater or equal than $0$.

| C | Simulation results of my program |
| --- | --- |
| 0.1 | 1.545 |
| 0.15 | 2.043 |
| 0.2 | 3.051 |
| 0.25 | 4.316 |
| 0.3 | 7.108 |
| 0.35 | 13.104 |
| 0.4 | 30.791 |
| 0.45 | 160.748 |

**question 2:** If the number of generated cells is limited, what should $P(\mathtt{round})$ satisfy?

**question 3:** what's the expected value of how many cells will be created when
$$
P(\mathtt{round}) = \exp(-\mathtt{round}/a),
$$
with $a>1$.

| a | Simulation results of my program |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.132 |
| 2 | 7.985 |
| 3 | 14.951 |
| 4 | 24.016 |
| 5 | 34.462 |
| 10 | 117.747 |
| 15 | 243.395 |
| 20 | 413.916 |
| 25 | 627.373 |
| 30 | 886.66 |
| 35 | 1180.763 |
| 40 | 1512.886 |
| 45 | 1888.011 |
| 50 | 2319.398 |
| 60 | 3274.22 |
| 70 | 4403.592 |
| 80 | 5690.979 |
| 90 | 7134.92 |